# How can I get unique members per category using perl?

Tags: perl, hash, unique

I used a hash to store members id.  I avoid the duplicity using the following validation:

```
if($cases{$type} != $member_id) {
    $cases{$type} = $member_id;
}
```

After that, I want to get the total of members by each $type. How can I do that?

I tried the following but do not work:

```
scalar(values $cases{$type});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach doesn't actually count how many members are in a given type; it just keeps track of what the last member added is.

To keep a count, consider using a hash-of-a-hash; use this for each `$member_id` you're adding:

```
$cases{$type}{$member_id} = 1;
```

The value for the hash assignment doesn't matter; it's just a way to use hash keys to maintain uniqueness.

Then, to get the number of members for a given type, use

```
scalar keys %{$cases{$type}}
```

Comment: That should be `scalar keys %{$cases{$type}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$member_id` as the key and use `grep` to find the count.
Store the `$type` like `$case{$member_id} = $type`

Use the following to print the count.

```
print scalar grep $case{$_} == $type, keys %case;
```